# Tiles from openstreetmap in retina display

Tags: ios, mapkit, openstreetmap, mktileoverlay

I have a problem when display tiles from openstreetmap through MKTileOverlay ; in retina display, text and labels are half size ( wrong scale ) and the map is unreadable.
I have tried to change tilesize , but with a different value the map is not correctly displayed ( i see nothing with 512, while tile overlaps with 128 )

[image]

How can i fix this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

Raster map tiles need to be designed specifically for retina displays to avoid this. I'd recommend something like [Mapbox](http://mapbox.com), whose API [automatically takes care of this](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-ios-sdk/#retina_support).

Otherwise, you'll have to implement your own custom `MKTileOverlayRenderer` and draw each 256px tile into a 512px `CGContext`. The tiles will appear blurry, though.